# In Java, can you link the garbage collection between two classes?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Suppose you have an instance a of Class A. Is it possible to create an instance b of class B, such that when a is garbage collected b will be garbage collected?

I know can cheat and create a reference to a in b, so a has to wait for b or something. What I want is for instance b to be deleted when a would naturally be deleted.

Comment: And what do you want to happen to any remaining live references to `b`?

Comment: If you don't already know about weak references (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) you should look them up; they seem related to what you're trying to do.

Comment: What is the problem you're experiencing right now due to B not being collected soon enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might know, we cannot force GC to work according to our wish.

But the first thought which can to mind was if A contains the instance of B, then naturally when a is GCed, b will be, too. This is just one scenario which came to my mind. I don't how you actually want to do it.

You can also use [weak references](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html).

Answer (score 4):

No. You can never force any object to be garbage collected. That's rather the point of garbage collection.

However, if the only reference to b is from a, then it is very likely that when the collector collects a, it will also collect b.

But to be honest, if you're worrying about when objects will be collected, the chances are you've doing it wrong. There should be no difference between dead and deleted objects as far as your program is concerned. Do you have a specific use for this that you would like to discuss?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can't even be sure when a object is collected (even System.gc() does not ensure that all unreferenced objects are collected) it is up to the garbage collection algorithm to decide if an unreferenced object is collected.

There are several GC strategies (you can set it when starting the JVM), your only option is to chose one that is exhaustive so it ensures that all unreferenced objects are collected(*). Then you'll have to be sure that both a and b get unreferenced at the same time (and that the gc is not called in between -I do not know of any way to ensure that-).

(*) Don't know if such algorithm does even exist. But if it does I am pretty sure it will have a heavy impact in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, if the instance of B is inside class A, it will get garbage collected automatically when A is destroyed. This example can be implemented this way:

```
   public class A {
`       B b;
     public A(B b) {
     this.b =b;
    }
   }

public class Test() {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
     A a = new A();
  }
}
```

When a goes out of scope, both a and b will get garbage collected(object b inside a will be garbage collected first).

I don't think you can call garbage collector for an specific object, it works automatically as needed(You cant force that). You can try to invoke it this way:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.gc();
```

It is not guaranted that the objects will be garbage callected when you execute the above code(Maybe the garbage collector is bussy)

Comment: As said by the others, there is no garbage collection guarantee at all, and also not about order. We only know that in your example `a.b` will not go earlier into "unreachable" state than `a` (since it is reachable from `a`), but this implies nothing about when the collector cleans them up (if he does so at all).

Comment: I might be making a mistake, but the reason i think b is collected first is because the garbage collector will not collect any object that is pointing to other object. Otherwise there is a possibility for garbage object to remain uncollected. Please correct me if i am mistaken. I do agree with all that there is no garbage collection guarantee.

Comment: The garbage collector does not need pointers to objects being collected - in fact, it only collects objects where **no pointers** from life objects point to. And the garbage collector can also collect cyclical object graphs, i.e. if your B had a reference back to A, this would not hinder the garbage collector from collecting both (as long as they are not referenced from elsewhere).

Comment: Yes that is what i wanted to say, maybe i did not express my self correctly. Because in my example A has a pointer to B, A cannot be collected straight away right(Here is where i got confused)? 
If we suppose B points to a third object, then we can for sure say that A will not be collected first at all(because has objects pointing somewhere). I think i understand better now. Thanks

Comment: No, when deciding whether to collect an object X, it does not matter at all to what objects X points. It only matters what objects point to X (e.g. if there is any path from a local variable on a life thread to X).

Comment: Sorry now i fully understand, i was all the time thinking the other way around :) Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

There are no events fired when an object is finalized, except a (non-guaranteed) call to obj.finalize().

You may place some code to finalize() of A. If you can somehow deduct the object B based on object A data (but not keeping an actual reference), you may at this point remove B from a global static Set, making it eligible for GC (not necessary at the same GC run though).